# Where can I find FATE Core RPG symbols?

Tags: fate-core, publishing

I want to write my own FATE Core adventures and rules. Where can I find either a font or individual graphical elements for: Overcome, Create an Advantage, Attack, and Defend.

Do these exist? Do I need to scan it from something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**You can download the official Fate Core font from [Evil Hat's licensing page](http://www.faterpg.com/licensing/)**, as well as the "Powered by Fate" logo.

> This font contains a small number of glyphs, supporting Fudge Dice faces (0, +, -), the Four Actions (A, D, C, O), and some stress track boxes.

They ask that you credit them in the works where you use it.

---

**Side note:** Since you're looking to publish Fate products, you should be aware that "FATE" [is no longer an acronym and technically should not be written in all-caps](http://www.faterpg.com/2013/fate-not-fate/).

Comment: Just wanted to give official confirmation as Evil Hat that BESW has all of this correct (including "Fate"), and has my thanks as the publisher.

Comment: Great answer. I am now using it. I am really excited about this. Thanks for the side notes as well!